# How can I do a countdown timer with html?

Tags: html, web, timer, countdown

I'm helping my I.T teacher to create easter eggs for some tasks, and I would like to create a countdown timer with html.
Explanation:
Everytime you enter into a website, the countdown timer starts.
Example:
I have a html code with a countdown timer at 30 min, if I go into the website, the countdown timer starts going down, but if I refresh the website, it reset.
I hope you will understand, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you'll want to use some javascript as well.

Comment: You'll need to program a browser extension that injects your javascript into every page the user visits to accomplish that. Also, don't come here expecting people to code for you. show some effort

Comment: Create a cookie on initial loading and update the counter value while closing/running. Check the cookie on loading the page and resume it using the value from the cookie.

Comment: Use expiring JWT returned by every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only javascript, without any server-side language you could store the time that is left in the localStorage variable, because after you exit the website/browser it will stay the same;

Example:

```
function countdown() {
    time = parseInt(localStorage.time); //All variables in localstorage are strings
    //Resets timer if cannot parse the localStorage.time variable or if the time is greater than 30 mins
    if(isNaN(time) || time > (30*60)) {
        alert("An error occured: time left variable is corrupted, resetting timer");
        localStorage.time = 30*60; //30 mins in seconds
        countdown();
        return null;    
    }
    //Decrementing time and recalling the function in 1 second
    time--;
    localStorage.time = time;
    setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}
```

You can add a function that turn seconds into: Minutes:Seconds and edit the function so it will change an element everytime it calls it self, or do something when the time reaches 0(don't forget to call it once, unless the timer won't run). Good luck!

I made a pen for you:
http://codepen.io/DaCurse0/pen/kkxVYP

It should have everything you need.

P.S: you should probably remove the alert when checking if timer is corrupted because it will show when the timer wasn't set.

Answer (score 0):

html code:

```
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="text">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="text">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="text">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="text">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
#clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

javascript code:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse("June 31,2017") - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

in the html documnet,include the new files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/count.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/flipclock.css">
```

hope it works...