# How to Change the display of countdown?

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

I have made a countdown with password protection. So this is my code

```js
var myTimer;
   function clock() {
     myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 180;
     var pass1 = 12;
     var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
     
     
     
     function myClock() {
       if (input==pass1){
       
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
       }
     }
   }
```

```html
<p id="demo">180</p>


<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="password" id="userInput" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" onclick="clock()" value="Start"/>
  <button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>
</form>
```

And this is the result.

[image]

But i dont like like that. I want to change into minutes. So 180 will be 3 minutes 0 seconds. And still countdown until 0 minute 0 second. How to change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a countdown timer with html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858157/how-can-i-do-a-countdown-timer-with-html)

Comment: @Dokksen I think that's right. But how it to convert to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by small modifications in existing code.  You need to calculate `mins` and `remaining seconds` from `seconds`. Refer following code sample.

```js
const mins = Math.floor(c / 60);
const remainingSecs = c % 60;
```

Integrating everything:

```js
var myTimer;

function clock() {
  myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
  var c = 180;
  var pass1 = 12;
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

  function myClock() {
    if (input == pass1) {
      c = parseInt(c);
      if (!isNaN(c) || c > 0) {
        c--;
        const mins = String(Math.floor(c / 60)).padStart(2, '0');
        const remainingSecs = String(c % 60).padStart(2, '0');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `${mins}:${remainingSecs}`;
        if (c === 0) {
          clearInterval(myTimer);
          alert("Reached zero");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Timer will appear here</p>


<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="password" id="userInput" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="clock()" value="Start" />
  <button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>
</form>
```

[String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: Thank you. How to keep the time in two digits. For example 9 becomes 09, 0 becomes 00.

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart method to pad additional '0's. I have updated my answer to incorporate the changes.